# get values from combobox and insert them

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I store records into combobox with the ID as the ValueMember and the NAME as the ViewMember, but when I insert the records to other tables by getting the ID from the same combobox, it gave me an error stated "cannot update or delete records", which leads the records didn't inserted.

Here's the combobox code I used

```vb
Using CMD As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
    With CMD
        .CommandText = "SELECT *FROM table1"
        .Connection = MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    End With
    DA = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(CMD)
    ntbl1 = New DataTable("table1")
    DA.Fill(ntbl1)
    With cmbEmployee
        .DataSource = ntbl1
        .DisplayMember = "name_employee"
        .ValueMember = "id_employee"
    End With
End Using
```

Here's the code to insert them

```vb
Using CMD As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
    With CMD
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO job VALUES ('NULL',@id_employee,@workarea)"
        .Connection = MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_employee", cmbEmployee.ValueMember)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@workarea", cmbWorkarea.Text)
        If MsgBox("Proceed?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
    End With
End Using
```

How do I avoid this error and if you may, include an example of the code please?

EDIT:
Use property Combobox.SelectedValue works just fine.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Wait for a moment until I updated the post.

Comment: Why are you inserting `'NULL'` and what is the data type of that column you are attempting to insert `NULL` into?

Comment: That 'NULL' is for the id work area. It use auto increment.

Comment: For one `NULL` shouldn't be in quotes if it's an `auto_increment` column or you'll get an "incorrect integer value" error (using the 6.9.9 Connector against a 5.6.24 database at least). Are your two parameters valid values when you step through the code?

Comment: `ValueMember` is the property to bind to.  You should use `SelectedValue` when retrievong data from the bound cbo

Comment: Yes, they all valids.

Wow! Thank you! I didn't know about this property. I didn't encountered that property on vs until now. Thank you once again. :)